# JAX-RS Jersey Error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: rest, file-upload, jersey, jax-rs

I wanted to implement a file-upload function for my jersey based rest server.

when i set my pom.xml (using maven) to:

```
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId> 
        <version>2.4.1</version> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jdk-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

i get following error:

```
JAX-RS Jersey Error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper.getContextClassLoaderPA()Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;
```

without the "jersey-media-multipart"-dependency the rest server is working but i cant use the file-upload functions.

Following the important part of source code:

```
ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(RestWebServer.class);
//resourceConfig.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
URI endPoint = new URI(pathServer);

server = JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer( endPoint, resourceConfig );
```

RestWebserver.java:

```
@Path("/fileupload")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile( 
        @FormParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream, 
        @FormParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) 
{
    String uploadedFileLocation = "c://" + fileDetail.getFileName();

    // save it
    saveToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

    String output = "File uploaded via Jersey based RESTFul Webservice to: " + uploadedFileLocation;

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a Jersey user so I am just guessing, but you probably have a jar mismatch.

Try replacing your second entry with this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-jdk-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Then i got "JdkHttpServerFactory cannot be resolved" for line "server = JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer( endPoint, resourceConfig );"

Comment: Its partly working, the uploadFile method throws following error:

WARNING: No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response me.whisper.server.RestWebServer.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition) at index 0.

org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response ....

Comment: Well, at this point I believe Stack Overflow etiquette suggests you should accept this answer (since it solved your posted problem) and then post a new question with your new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basing my guess on the [chapter 8](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart), have you registered your client/server code?

Comment: ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(RestWebServer.class);   resourceConfig.packages("org.glassfish.jersey.examples.multipart");
resourceConfig.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
URI endPoint = new URI(pathServer);
is not working...

Comment: Are you using Netbeans and its template by any chance?